# How to manually unbind a key mapping in the Irssi IRC client?

Tags: irssi

I accidentaly bound the <kbd>K</kbd> key to the `scroll_backward` function. Now I’m unable to unbind it from [Irssi](http://www.irssi.org), since every time I press <kbd>K</kbd> it justs executes the function and refuses to write the character. I tried to fix the problem by reinstalling Irssi, but it didn’t work.

Does anyone know where’s the file where the bindings are stored? I think manual unbind is the only solution but I can’t find the file.

Comment: I'm on jailbroken iOS 8.1.2. The `grep irssi` command didn't work, it just kept the terminal on a wait state (so i was unable to type another command).

Comment: `lsof | grep irssi`, not `grep irssi`. If you run `grep` by itself it reads from stdin, ie your keyboard. You can press ctrl+C or ctrl+D to escape that.

Answer (score 2):

The irssi configuration file is, by default at least, located in `~/.irssi/config`.

If irssi is currently running, use `/save` first to save any changes done to the configuration before editing it, so any changes don't get lost.

Within the configuration file, the `keyboard` section contains the keyboard bindings. Inside that, you may find for example:

`keyboard = (
  { key = "k"; id = "scroll_backward"; data = ""; }
  ...
);`

Just delete the unwanted entry. Now, use `/reload` in irssi, if it's still running and you should be able to use the `k` key again.

Comment: I had done exactly this - accidental binding of a number, suddenly I couldn't type the `1` and any URLs etc that I pasted, had it stripped because the config was trying to execute the binding (eg, `google.com/?q=123` became `google.com/?q=23`). Scanned through the config file at `~/.irssi/config` and deleted the errant lines. Yay, works!

Comment: An alternative is to add `/bind k scroll_backward` to `~/.irssi/startup`

Answer (score 0):

I can see your struggle here... I can think of many options:

- you just did it, so you can still use the <kbd>↑</kbd> (up) key and edit your command to: `/bind -delete k`
- you realize your error too late (the `/bind k` is out of history) or the up key is not available:

  - if you didn't save your configuration: just type `/reload`
  - you did `/save`... as the others says you edit your `~/.irrsi/config` to remove the problematic line in the `keyboard` section, then reload
- you disabled one of the letter required to type `/reload`: `/rel` should be enough, otherwise since v0.8.2 you can `pkill -HUP irssi` from another term